# how to store on server , and access big wordlist most efficiently ?

Tags: python, database, dictionary, tree, store

I need for my webapp a wordlist file with about 200k words, and I would like display words, which begins with a certain substring for example : 'clo'. Should i just store it in database, and access it with a simple query? I thought about creating a tree from this wordlist and store it in cache, and just search this tree to find appropriate words, In my opion this should be better solution,especially when it comes to greater amount of requests per minute.
How would you solve this issue in most efficient way?

Comment: The database solution won't probably be effective since you'll need to do lots of queries with a "like XXX" statement.
Your second solution seems more efficient.
Take a look a this answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/112559/2003420

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie); I've implemented such a solution in C++ for a Ruzzle-solver program and I can confirm that it's *extremely* efficient - although, in Python you surely are going to get worse performance due to the fact the Python's equivalent of a trie node like this:

```c
class AlphaTrie
{
    // Pointers for the next trie nodes
    std::auto_ptr<AlphaTrie> next[26];
    // true if the current node marks the end of a word
    bool final;
    // ...
};
```

is going to contain less trivial data structures (e.g. accessing a Python list is slower than a "dumb" C array stored directly in the node) and thus have a bigger overhead.

Comment: this seems to be what I'm looking for. I wanted to implement tree with nodes that contain single letters, and variable 'final' , I havent thought about putting there letters from parental nodes. Thanks for help, I'll try this.